# How to not repeat math operations on my calculator app

Tags: java, android, calculator

I wanted to know how can I prevent the math operators from repeating.

for example this is what I get `9+++++****----////`

Is there something that can be done to prevent the operations from being able to repeat?
Your help is much appreciated thank you.

// Here is my code:

```java
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button_clear, button_addition, button_dot, button_multiply,button_divide,button_subtract,
    button_one,button_two,button_three,button_four,button_five,button_six,button_seven,button_eight,
            button_nine,
    button_zero,button_equal;

    TextView displayTv, result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        displayTv=findViewById(R.id.displayTV);
        result=findViewById(R.id.answerCalculated);

        asignId(button_clear, R.id.clear);
        asignId(button_addition, R.id.addition);
        asignId(button_subtract, R.id.subtract);
        asignId(button_multiply, R.id.multiplication);
        asignId(button_divide, R.id.divide);
        asignId(button_dot, R.id.dot);
        asignId(button_one, R.id.button_one);
        asignId(button_two, R.id.button_two);
        asignId(button_three, R.id.button_three);
        asignId(button_four, R.id.button_four);
        asignId(button_five, R.id.button_five);
        asignId(button_six, R.id.button_six);
        asignId(button_seven, R.id.button_seven);
        asignId(button_eight, R.id.button_eight);
        asignId(button_nine, R.id.button_nine);
        asignId(button_zero, R.id.button_zero);
        asignId(button_equal,R.id.button_equal);
    }

    private void asignId(Button btn, int id) {
        btn=findViewById(id);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //set view to button

        Button button=(Button)view;

        //get buttonText
        String buttonText=button.getText().toString();

        //get DisplayedText
        String displayedText=displayTv.getText().toString();

        //displayed text plus button text
        displayedText=displayedText+buttonText;

        displayTv.setText(displayedText);

        String finalResult=getResult(displayedText);


        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.clear:
                displayTv.setText("");
                result.setText("0");
                break;

            case R.id.button_equal:
                if(!finalResult.equals("ERR")){
                    result.setText(finalResult);

                }
        }



        //


    }

    private String getResult(String data) {
        try{
            Context context  = Context.enter();
            context.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
            Scriptable scriptable = context.initStandardObjects();
            String finalResult =  context.evaluateString(scriptable,data,"Javascript",1,null).toString();
            if(finalResult.endsWith(".0")){
                finalResult = finalResult.replace(".0","");
            }
            return finalResult;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "Err";
        }


    }
}
```

I have found this answer thats similar to mine  but the difference is that they are using Kotlin and I'm using java.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to check the last character in the `displayedText` in the `onClick`, and if it is a math operator, then you remove it from the text, here is some code:

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    //set view to button
    Button button = (Button) view;

    //get buttonText
    String buttonText = button.getText().toString();

    //get DisplayedText
    String displayedText = displayTv.getText().toString();

    // check if last character in displayedText is a math operator
    if (displayedText.length() > 0) {
        char lastChar = displayedText.charAt(displayedText.length() - 1);
        if (isMathOperator(lastChar) && isMathOperator(buttonText.charAt(0))) {
            // remove last character
            displayedText = displayedText.substring(0, displayedText.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    //displayed text plus button text
    displayedText = displayedText + buttonText;

    displayTv.setText(displayedText);

    String finalResult = getResult(displayedText);

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.clear:
            displayTv.setText("");
            result.setText("0");
            break;

        case R.id.button_equal:
            if (!finalResult.equals("ERR")) {
                result.setText(finalResult);
            }
    }
}
```

And the isMathOperator is just a method to check if the character is a one of the 4 math operators:

```java
private boolean isMathOperator(char c) {
    return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/';
}
```